# Any way to refresh Chrome from the DevTools interface?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to refresh a Chrome browser window from the Developer Tools interface? It's getting pretty annoying to leave DevTools, go over to the browser, refresh, and then go back to DevTools.

I was hoping there was a button, or menu item at least, or anything that I could use inside DevTools to refresh the actual browser page.

Comment: I swear I don't always whine about such trivial things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Tools recognizes the normal key binding for page refresh. That is typically:

**Windows** - <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>

**Mac** - <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>

The page you are examining will refresh, even if DevTools is running in a separate window.